# Android DialogFragment with array of strings open in middle of array?

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I'm opening a dialog so my user can choose a year from a list.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle("Choose Year")
       .setItems(years, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // The 'which' argument contains the index position
               // of the selected item

           }
       });
return builder.create();
```

The `years` variable is a `String[]` but it could be up to 100 items long. Is there any way to make the Dialog open showing a specific item in the list in the visible initial range? For example, if the array of years goes from 1913-2013 it always opens to 1913. Is there anyway to make it open in the middle of the list at 1980?

Answer (score 0):

try  inflate a layout with a ListView in a DialogFragment's onCreateView method.